# How to test openshift action_hooks prior to git push to Openshift server

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have been looking at Openshift docs and on Stack Overflow for a while now and I can't seem to get any answers.

I want to know what the standard pattern is for developing applications for deployment on Openshift? I am especially concerned with testing of action_hooks prior to deployment. I found this particularly troublesome when I was using a DIY cartridge recently where I had to deal with downloading dependencies in my build script prior to starting my application. As my application kept failing to start every time I made a change and pushed it (I only did this as an initial test of the Openshift service, I would never develop like this). I ended up having to ssh onto my instance and resolve the issue by trial and error (not really ideal).

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.
Thanks

Comment: Can anyone give any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I am aware of to test action hooks on OpenShift is to ssh into an application and run them manually from the command line.  This way you can quickly debug & update them.  Then copy them to your git repository and do a git push to deploy the new code.

The only other way I can think of would be to run OpenShift Origin (v2) locally and use that to test with.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. Is this the kind of thing you had in mind? https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_deployment_guide_vm.html